# Looking for iOS 15.7 support files for XCode14

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14, ios15.7

My iPhoneXR updated to 15.7, and XCode updated to 14. Which happened right as MacOS was updating, so I'm wondering if something got wonked with the XCode update. Now I can't program my phone.

Looking in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

there is no 15.7. But the various github repositories that have various support files, none of them include 15.7. Is there a place these are stored at?

When I open the "downloads" window for XCode, it's just a blank window.

Comment: Try to use the 15.6 files (just rename them).

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: If you have an active Apple Developer paid membership, download and install Xcode 13.4.1 from the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/). Apple claims it will work with iOS 15.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved in the latest release candidate of Xcode 14.0.1 which can be downloaded directly from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/). Apparently, Apple left out all support for 15.7 in the first release of Xcode 14.

Comment: But you can't publish Apps compiled with a beta version of Xcode - I just received this message from Apple: <<Your app or its metadata contains references to a pre-release version of Apple software, products, or hardware. Apps with compatibility references to a pre-release candidate version of an Apple operating system or pre-released Apple products or hardware are not in compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.>>

Comment: @MarkMiles Once the device has been made ready for development using Xcode 14.0.1 RC, it can connect to Xcode 14.0

Answer (score 24):

The 15.7 support files can be downloaded from: https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport

Unzip the file in the DeviceSupport folder and (re)start xCode.

Comment: works for me! should be marked as the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work in Xcode 14, I already tried, you need to download Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: I've downloaded and put the unzipped folder in the appropriate place but Xcode doesn't seem to recognise my efforts, is there any more to this? (I've tried it with both 13.4.1 & 14.0.1)

Comment: It worked for me with Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: I downloaded 15.7 support, but it does not work with my iOS 15.7.3 device. Any help?

Comment: Not working for Xcode 14.3, added to device support folder but cant detect. Been trying to create iPhone 7 simulator on iOS 15.7 but dont have the option under dropdown; only 15.5. Anyone manage to get this work?

Comment: @SebastiaanKle How can I get iOS 15.8 Device Support Version?

Answer (score 4):

See [Xcode 14 Release Notes:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes)

> Xcode 14 cannot be used with iOS 15.7 for development. (99847608)
> Workaround: Use Xcode 13.4.1 with iOS 15.7.

Comment: This blows me away that Apple's auto ecosystem automagically upgrades my phone to be secure, and moves me to a version of XCode which won't program it. Went ahead and updated to iOS16 to get around it. But dumbfounded that the Attention to Detail(tm) company gets this type of thing wrong now days

Answer (score 4):

**DO NOT download what amounts to an Xcode patch from some random github repository and then patch your build system with it, like suggested in another answer!**

If you can't or do not want to upgrade to Xcode 14, and instead want to patch your Xcode 13 installation, you should download the files directly from Apple. The following describes the process step by step.

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
2. Click the blue "download" button.
3. A menu opens. Select "website" from the menu.
4. This will download an xib archive. This file is large (between 7 and 8GB)
5. Open the xib archive in a Finder window, right-click on Xcode and select "Show Package Contents". Then navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
6. Inside you will see directories for iOS versions. Choose the ones you are missing in your Xcode 13 installation and copy them over to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`