# How to update xcode to 13.4.1 or to add support to iOS 15.7 in xcode 14?

Tags: ios, xcode

My iphone 7 was updated to iOS 15.7. my current xcode (12.5.1) doesn't support it. But from the app store I can only update xcode to the last one (14) and 14 seam to support only iOS 16. So is it possible to update my xcode to 13.4.1 OR in xcode 14 to have the iOS 15.7 support ?

Comment: You can use Xcode 14 with iOS 15.7 devices.  You can also find older Xcode downloads on the apple developer site

Comment: You can download Xcode 13.4.1 [from this page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14 does not support iOS 15.7 devices. Xcode 14.0.1 RC does. See details and other workarounds here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721778/looking-for-ios-15-7-support-files-for-xcode14/73739710#73739710].
By the way, once the device is prepared for development with Xcode 14.0.1, Xcode 14.0 can connect to it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I am on 14.0.1 and can't have 15.7 support